# Can someone please tell what the code would be to check ether balance at a particular point in time?

Tags: ether, balances

I want to understand how to check ether balance at a particular point in time.

Comment: Please add more details so that your question can be answered. Where are you checking the ether balance? In some ether wallet / in your ethereum node?

Comment: I am checking it in ethereum node

Comment: by coding or you by using a tool?

Answer (score 1):

Check the balance using below command -

```
eth.getBalance(accountAddress)
```

In order to see the list of accounts, type -

```
eth.accounts
```

This would give you an array of existing accounts and then you can check balance for any account by giving it's index -

```
eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[i])
```